# WP Meta query for a custom post type based on two values

Tags: custom-post-types, meta-query

I'm hoping you can help me out and give me a tip on something I'm trying to achieve and failing miserably.

I'm working on a WordPress real-estate theme - Real homes. Here is the link to the website: https://lnobrerealestate.pt/

What I'm trying to achieve is to have two sections with featured properties, one for sales and one for rentals.

So in order to do that, I need to change the query that gets the posts. The original query that gets a list of featured properties is:

```
/* Featured Properties Query Arguments */
$featured_properties_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'property',
    'posts_per_page'    => 12,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'REAL_HOMES_featured',
            'value'     => 1,
            'compare'   => '=',
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
);
```

This query gets the first 12 properties that are marked as featured. What I need to add is another condition that would check if the property status is "For Sale" or "For Rent".

I can get an array of property statuses with this query:

```
        $property_status_terms = get_terms(array(
                'taxonomy'   => "property-status",
                'orderby'    => 'name',
                'order'      => 'ASC',
                'hide_empty' => false
            )
        );

        if (! empty($property_status_terms)) {
            foreach ($property_status_terms as $property_status) {
                echo '<p>' . $property_status->name . '</p>';
            }
        }
```

So I though that based on these two queries I can do the following:

```
/* Featured Properties Query Arguments */
    $featured_properties_args = array(
        'post_type'         => 'property',
        'posts_per_page'    => 12,
        'meta_query'        => array(
            'relation' => 'AND',
            array(
                'key'       => 'REAL_HOMES_featured',
                'value'     => 1,
                'compare'   => '=',
                'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
            ),
            get_terms(array(
            'taxonomy'       => 'property-status',
            'value'     => array('For Rent', 'Arrendamento'),
            'compare'   => 'IN',
             )
             )
        )
    );
```

I'm comparing the array of property statuses with two values - for rent in case of English and Arrendamento in case of Portuguese.

This query doesn't result in what I'm trying to achieve and I can't get what I'm missing here. Seems quite straight forward.

I'm hoping you can give me a suggestion.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, so that's a little example of what I call "wishful coding" ;)

```
get_terms(array(
    'taxonomy'       => 'property-status',
    'value'     => array('For Rent', 'Arrendamento'),
    'compare'   => 'IN',
) )
```

You use [`get_terms`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_terms/) function here, which will

> Retrieve the terms in a given taxonomy or list of taxonomies.

And you use this inside of meta_query part of a query, which is used to query custom fields.

So there is no way it could do anything at all... Terms are not valid meta_query queries...

But of course it can be done... All you need to do is to check docs for [`WP_Query`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query)...

You already have this:

```
$featured_properties_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'property',
    'posts_per_page'    => 12,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'REAL_HOMES_featured',
            'value'     => 1,
            'compare'   => '=',
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    )
);
```

and you know it gets you featured properties. So all you have to do is to add your [tax query](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Taxonomy_Parameters) in there:

```
$featured_properties_args = array(
    'post_type'         => 'property',
    'posts_per_page'    => 12,
    'meta_query'        => array(
        array(
            'key'       => 'REAL_HOMES_featured',
            'value'     => 1,
            'compare'   => '=',
            'type'      => 'NUMERIC'
        )
    ),
    'tax_query'         => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy'  => 'property-status',
            'field'     => 'name',
            'terms'     => array('For Rent', 'Arrendamento'),
        )
    ) 
);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for helping, it worked perfectly. I was so close but yet so far away :)